# Infinitesimal work

Tags: notation, mathematical-physics

It is usually to find that $\delta W=f\cdot dr$ is the definition of *infinitesimal work*. My question is:

(1) if $f$ is a smooth vector field (force), and

(2) $dr$ is the differential of a function $r:I\to \mathbb{R}^3$

How is defined the *product* $f\cdot dr$?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In $\mathbb{R}^3$ using Cartesian coordinates,the displacement $\vec{dr}$ is a vector:
$$
\vec{dr}=(dx,dy,dz)
$$
and the force is a vector 
$$
\vec f=(f_x,f_y,f_z)
$$

so $\vec f \cdot \vec{dr}=f_xdx+f_ydy+f_zdz$ is a [differential 1-form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form).